# iOS - local notification - custom vibration or vibrate for longer duration

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, iphone-vibrate

I am trying to build an iPhone app that works like an alarm, I am using UILocalNotification

**Problem**

- I would like the phone to vibrate for a longer duration. However currently it vibrates only once.

**Alternative Approaches**

1. Is it possible to use custom vibration patters ?(http://www.pcworld.com/article/242238/how_to_use_custom_vibrations_in_ios_5.html)
2. Is it possible to execute a method, when the push notification is fired ? (but the app might not even be running, and yet it needs to work)
3. Is NSTimer an option ? (but the app might not even be running, and yet it needs to work)
4. Is there any other alternate ?

Comment: Actually, it's not possible to do custom vibrations without accessing private APIs, which will get you rejected in the app store review.

Comment: Thanks Shiming, is there any alternate solution to this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot change the duration of vibration,or make it,for example,vibrate several times(untill you don't make several notifications).

Only way to make custom vibration is to do it from the app, while it is running, no other way for you.

Comment: How about involving some private APIs? For example calling `AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration` in the background mode.